# Клик по последней ячейке таблицы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть таблица, которая заполняется через PHP:

```html
<table id="position">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Статус</th>
      <th scope="col">IP-адрес</th>
      <th scope="col">Последняя активность</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='{$ip}'>
      <th scope='row'>{$id}</th>
      <td>{$online}</td>
      <td><a href='http://{$ip}' target='_blank'>{$ip}</a></td>
      <td>{$lastActive}</td>
      <td id='button'><i class='bi bi-trash' style='font-size: 20px' ;></i></td>
    </tr>";
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Есть отслеживание нажатия по строке таблицы:

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('#position tbody');
tbody.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
const cell = e.target.closest('td');
if (!cell) {return;} // Quit, not clicked on a cell
const row = cell.parentElement;
console.log(row.rowIndex, row.id);
```

Проблема в том, что функция отслеживает клик по всей строке таблицы, а мне нужно только по последней ячейке (с `id='button'`). Пробовал несколько вариантов - ничего не помогло - отслеживалась только ячейка первой строки, остальные игнорировались.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто уточните селектор в `closest()` :

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('#position tbody');
tbody.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const cell = e.target.closest('td:last-child');
  if (!cell) {
    return;
  } // Quit, not clicked on a cell
  const row = cell.parentElement;
  console.log(row.rowIndex, row.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="position">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Статус</th>
      <th scope="col">IP-адрес</th>
      <th scope="col">Последняя активность</th>
      <th scope="col">button</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='{$ip}'>
      <th scope='row'>{$id}</th>
      <td>{$online}</td>
      <td><a href='http://{$ip}' target='_blank'>{$ip}</a></td>
      <td>{$lastActive}</td>
      <td id='button'><i class='bi bi-trash' style='font-size: 20px'>button</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Всё, сработало, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

как-то не нормально отслеживать клики на ячейке целиком. Добавьте внутрть кнопку или ссылку, и к ней прицепите клик.

```
<td>
   <a href="#" class="remove">
     <i class='bi bi-trash' style='font-size: 20px';></i>
   </a>
</td>
```

и jquery (раз уж есть в тегах)

```
$(".remove").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

если строки добавляются динамически то добавьте идентификатор к tbody

```
$("tbody#rows").on('click', '.remove', function(){....});
```

Если уж надо сделать таки клики прямо в ячейки, то класс `.remove` переносите в сам `<td>`, в остальном код не изменится.

в общем говоря, все нужные ячейки нужно пометить одним классом и с ним и работать.